# Hibernate: bad performance when removing element from many-to-many relation

Tags: performance, hibernate

I have to Classes (UserSet and User) which have a many-to-many relation (i.e. every user can belong to some UserSets). In the database there is a UserSet Table, a User Table and an 'in between' Table (UsersToUserSets).
Now, if I want to remove a user from a UserSet by doing

```
 userSet.getUsers().remove(user);
 session.flush()
```

Hibernate first fetches **all** users belonging to userSet and then removes the one user and updates the 'inbetween' table.

As there may be thousands of users belonging to a UserSet this is very bad for the performance. Is there a way to avoid that all of the users are fetched?

The interesting parts of the mapping files look like this:

```
<class name="...UserSet"> 
...
    <set name="users" table="T_UM_USERS2USER_SETS">
        <key column="FK_USER_SET_ID" />
        <many-to-many column="FK_USER_ID"
            class="...User" />
    </set>
...
</class>

<class name="...User"> 
...
    <set name="userSets" table="T_UM_USERS2USER_SETS" inverse="true">
        <key column="FK_USER_ID" />
        <many-to-many column="FK_USER_SET_ID" class="...UserSet"  />
    </set>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All users for a particular UserSet are fetched because you're calling `userSet.getUsers().remove(user)`. Performing any operation on a lazy collection causes collection to be fetched. What you can do is:

1) If userSets cardinality is lower than that of users (e.g. given user would only belong to few userSets) you can switch the inverse end of this relationship and invoke `user.getUserSets().remove(userSet)` - I'm assuming here you want to remove the *association* only and not the actual entity.

OR

2) You can define a named SQL query to delete the association row from `T_UM_USERS2USER_SETS` table and execute it.

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion did the trick. I had already tried the second one, and although it worked per se, there occured several problems at other parts of the program (i.e. while in the same session, the collections didn't have the same state as the database, and so on).